# A Generalized Mechanism for Gale-Shapley

Tags: game-theory

I am working on some problems in my applied graph theory course, and we have
just gotten to matching problems. We are currently working on a graph problem
where instead of there being two types of agents in Gale-Shapley, all of the
$n$ agents can establish preferences on the other $n-1.$ I am asked to find
a mechanism to ensure a stable matching or if I cannot ensure a stable matching,
attempt to find a property that biconditionally prevents a stable matching
from existing. I was able to pretty clearly figure out that the latter is
true, since we can easily see from the preference profile
$$1: 2 \succ 3 \succ 1$$
$$2: 3 \succ 1 \succ 2$$
$$3: 1 \succ 2 \succ 3$$
that we cannot form a stable matching since we will have a blocking pair in
any of the three matchings. However, I am having problems figuring out what
is occurring that prevents stable matches from happening. Does it involve the
number of agents? Is it a property of the preference profile? Any assistance
will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused by your example.  Doesn't $n$ to be an even number?  Unless you have a different definition of matching than in the classical Gale-Shapley setup.

Comment: Okay, I guess you mean that two people will be paired up and the third leftover.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is a subtle variation on the so-called Roommate Problem; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_roommates_problem

The difference seems to be that you allow an odd set of agents and thus one may be left out. (The original Roommate problem assumes $2k$ agents.) The link above points to a page with details for an algorithm that determines if a stable matching exists and, if so, finds one.